# Creating 3D geographical maps for physical fields in qgis

Tags: qgis, interpolation, 3d, contour

We need to reproduce 3D maps of a certain physical property on a geographical area changing with depth (in the case of the example these are surfaces of equal subsurface temperature). The example graph from a scientific publication looks as follows:
[image: subsurface temperature distribution]

How it is possible to reproduce this with qgis or, possibly, with an equivalent software?
The input data can be in the form of measured subsurface temperatures (or other property, for example, subsea temperature, salinity or whatever) at certain points sampled at some depths, and the surfaces are to be calculated by interpolating them, like it is done for bathymetric curves.

Comment: If it's 3D plots you're after (in the sense of expoting graphics or similar for e.g. papers) and don't mind scripting a little, I think [R](https://www.r-project.org) is worth a try. I'm no pro in R, simply because I don't like the coding style, but it's astonishingly easy to get into and produces dynamic high quality plots on the fly. there's very good spatial and 3D plotting support via plugins and very good documenation..

Comment: possibly golden software: SURFER.